# Access DevExpress JavaScript objects for nested fields

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

When I render DevExpress MVC controls for nested fields, using a custom `FormBuilder` class of my own, I'm using the naming convention of `ModelName.FieldName`.  This fixes binding issues I was having, but I now need client-side access to the JavaScript objects that are created for the control.

In the past, I would find an object called `FieldName`.  For nested fields, what is the naming pattern for the JavaScript object name (since `ModelName.FieldName` would not be a suitable JavaScript object name), and is there perhaps an alternative way to access the object by passing in the full field name as a parameter to some JavaScript method (something like `AllControls.GetControl('ModelName.FieldName')`)?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var textBoxSettings = new TextBoxSettings
{
    Name = "ModelName.FieldName",       
};
writer.Write(devExpress.TextBox(textBoxSettings).GetHtml());
```

**UPDATE:**
It appears that DevExpress does indeed render objects with the name `ModelName.FieldName`. I'm not sure how to access those objects in JavaScript - is there some kind of escape sequence to treat the entire phrase as a single variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress does actually create the JavaScript object with a variable name in the form `ModelName.FieldName`.

To access that object in JavaScript, you can use the format:

```
var myControl = window['ModelName.FieldName'];
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding the 'DevExpress' way to access controls dynamically is to use the control collection functions

```
var nameTextBox = 
ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName('ModelName.FieldName')
```